# BeautifulSoup: parse part page (tumblr template), unexpected result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to parse a part of html page with BeautifulSoup.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

body = """Some text
<body{block:PermalinkPage} class="inside"{/block:PermalinkPage}>
Some text
"""

print BeautifulSoup(body, 'html5lib')
```

Output is

```
<html><head></head><body>Some text
<body{block:permalinkpage} block:permalinkpage}="" class="inside" {="">
Some text
</body{block:permalinkpage}></body></html>
```

The desired output is

```
<html><head></head><body>Some text
<body{block:PermalinkPage} class="inside"{/block:PermalinkPage}>
Some text
</body{block:permalinkpage}></body></html>
```

Why does the BeautifulSoup change this code so much? Is it possible to force it to work like I expect? What library should I use to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like valid html (though I could be wrong). Underneath BeautifulSoup uses a parser, which in this case you've explicitly forced to be [`html5lib`](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python). If the underlying parser can't handle your input, bs4 won't either.

It looks like you are feeding it some logic template language that can be processed into html (like for example [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) or [slim](http://slim-lang.com/)), but it's hard to say without any context.